# BizTalk 2016 Export Bindings error message

Tags: binding, export, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am trying to export bindings from BizTalk 2016 Enterprise edition and I am getting the following error message:

> Method not found: 'Boolean
>    Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.Binding.ServiceRef.get_AnalyticsEnabled()'

Is there something I missed when installing BTS?

Installed updates are BTS2016-KB4014788-ENU.exe and BTS2016-KB4132957-ENU.exe

Comment: BTS2016-KB4014788-ENU.exe and BTS2016-KB4132957-ENU.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've are mixing Feature Packs and CUs

BTS2016-KB4014788-ENU.exe is Feature Pack 1 with CU3

BTS2016-KB4132957-ENU.exe is CU 5

I would advice against that and have [blogged](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/biztalk-2016-feature-pack-3-cu5/) about it.  If you are using Enterprise, I would recommend installing Feature Packs only, as this way you get all the fixes from the CUs as well as some features that you may want to use.  For those using BizTalk Standard just install the CU as Feature Packs are available for Enterprise only.

The feature packs are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/configure-the-feature-pack), the latest currently is [Feature Pack 3 with CU 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57077).

Analytics is something released with Feature Pack 1. [Send BizTalk tracking data to Azure Application Insights or Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/send-tracking-data-to-azure-application-insights-using-biztalk-server) which probably changed some of the Adapters to hook into this, and both CU 4 and CU 5 updated some adapters, so this feature might then not be available for those adapters.

So my advice, try installing Feature Pack 3.   If that throws an error, you may have to uninstall CU5 first and then install Feature Pack 3.

Comment: Thank you.  updating with Feature Pack 3 with CU 5 did the trick.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you - I thought I had.  Please let me know if I did not check it correctly.