# BizTalk-2016 Feature Pack 3 Install after Cumulative Update 6

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have installed BizTalk 2016 and BizTalk 2016 Cumulative Update 6 BTS2016-KB4477494-ENU.exe successfully.

Next I want to install feature pack 3 for Biztalk 2016.

But the Feature pack 3 comes with CU6 which is already installed. I downloaded BizTalk 2016 CU6 with Feature Update 3 BTS2016-KB4294900-ENU.exe and tried to install it. I am getting errors.

Should I uninstall CU6 and then install CU6 AND FeaturePack 3?

Answer (score 1):

The advice I posted on my blog [BizTalk 2016 – Feature Pack 3 & CU5](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/biztalk-2016-feature-pack-3-cu5/) still holds.  Do not try and install both CUs and Feature Packs.  So yes, I would try uninstalling CU6 and installing the latest Feature Pack instead.

> So which should you install?  I’ve seen people post a few questions about installing Feature Packs in conjunction with Cumulative Updates and here is my advice and reasoning.
>
> For BizTalk 2016 Enterprise, always install the latest Feature Packs only.  Your server will be up to date and contain some extra features you may need later, even if you don’t need them now. Feature Packs are only available for Enterprise, are cumulative and contain both the previous Feature Packs and all the CUs so no need to install those separately.
>
> For BizTalk 2016 Standard or Branch, always install the CUs only.
>
> For BizTalk 2016 Developer, you will want to keep this in line with whatever your Production server has.
>
> Mixing CUs and Feature Packs either causes the installation to fail, or can cause strange issues. e.g.
>
> - [BizTalk Cumulative Update installation error: Cannot proceed with
>     installation Biztalk server pack is installed BizTalk 2016 Export](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2017/10/11/biztalk-cumulative-update-installation-error-cannot-proceed-with-installation-biztalk-server-pack-is-installed/)
> - [Bindings error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543628/biztalk-2016-export-bindings-error-message)

**Note**: The OP is using the updated [Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016 Feature Update 3 with CU6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57961) rather than the outdated [Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016 Feature Update 3 with CU5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57077) they still link to from [Configure the feature pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/configure-the-feature-pack)